# is.null() returns true for list with non-null values

Tags: json, r, list, sapply

The context is an R6 class with a slot called "jsonResult".
Within this class there is a method that executes the GET request and processes the result.

Within this method, "jsonResult" is accessed with "self$jsonResult" in compliance with R6 syntax.

Here I have applied fromJSON() to an HTTP response to generate a list.
The base case is a good list where the request got me what I wanted.
When I attempt to clean it up via sapply(), it removes the data as if it was null.

Here is the code:

```
> print(jsonResult)
[[1]]
          InputValue      KEGG Pathway ID 
         "Psme2b-ps" "mmu03050//mmu04612" 

[[2]]
     InputValue KEGG Pathway ID 
       "Psmb10"      "mmu03050" 

> dput(jsonResult)
list(structure(c("Psme2b-ps", "mmu03050//mmu04612"), .Names = c("InputValue", 
"KEGG Pathway ID")), structure(c("Psmb10", "mmu03050"), .Names = c("InputValue", 
"KEGG Pathway ID")))


> jsonResult <- sapply(self$jsonResult, 
    FUN=function(x) {
            x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
               unlist(x)
        })

> print(jsonResult)
list()

> dput(jsonResult)
list()
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(jsonResult)`?

Comment: dput() output added

Comment: what is `self$jsonResult`?  if use `jsonResult` instead of `self$jsonResult` then result is not NULL.

Comment: Have you tried using a different function from the apply family? I often find that `sapply` doesn't output what is expected

Comment: What are you trying to clean up? Looks like there are no NA's in the list you supplied?

Comment: jsonResult <- sapply() is called within a public method of an R6 class.  Therefore the the slot "jsonResult" is accessed with self$jsonResult

Comment: a "KEGG Pathway ID " is not guaranteed to exist for a given input value.  In practice "jsonResult" will be a list with thousands of elements, hundreds of which will be null.

Comment: Can you provide an example where there is a NULL value? Running the code without `self` works fine for me, providing an example where `self` can be used would be helpful as well.

Comment: thanks @jdb.  removing "self" fixed it for me because, embarrasingly, it turned out that slots no longer contained jsonResult, since it is not used elsewhere.  a call to a non-existent attribute that silently fails during compile (and execution) is one of the many joy's of R.  how can I delete this stupid question from SO?

Answer (score 0):

Removing "self" fixed it because, embarrassingly, I had previously removed "jsonResult" from slots in the class definition, as it is not used elsewhere.  Thus, "self$jsonResult"  was a call to a non-existent attribute that silently failed during compile and execution.

Comment: since it seems I cannot remove this question, which would be ideal, how can I improve this post to make it somehow more useful to others?